# How to remove strings of length 5 from a set?

Tags: java, string, set

I want to remove strings of length 5 from a set, but it keeps outputting the set itself.

```
public void remove5()
{
Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
newSet.add("hello");
newSet.add("my");
newSet.add("name");
newSet.add("is");
newSet.add("nonsense");
for(String word: newSet)
{
    if(word.length()==5)
    {
        newSet.remove(word); // Doesn't Help - throws an error Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
    System.out.println(newSet);
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
my
name
is
nonsense
```

(hello was removed because it's 5 characters)

But I get this everytime:

```
hello
my
name
is 
nonsense
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Instead of removing your old code, turning several of the helpful answers you got int non sequiturs, I think it would have been better to add the new code at the end of your question, or perhaps even asked a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Iterator<String> it= newStr.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) { // iterate
   String word = it.next();
   if(word.length() == 5) { // predicate
      it.remove();  // remove from set through iterator - action
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why String[] setStr = set1.toArray(new String[0]); is needed? Why can't I just iterate through a set? Your method works.

Comment: why to create a new String[] ? Why not use Iterator ?

Comment: @MacosxIam: it is to avoid concurrent modification exception. but you can remove the  element from the iterator instance directly

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley I was trying exactly the same code, and I did not get the exception, have been thinkinh what might be the reason, its exactly same code copy pasted.

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley nops, I am trying code of Macosx Iam, the originial one.

Comment: I'll pick your solution because it's the simplest :). The simpler, the better!

Comment: @PrinceJohnWesley I think I have got the reason, In my case this is the set before removing [my, name, nonsense, is, hello], "hello" is at the end, so when I remove element from the set exception does not come, and I believe if hello is somewhere in the middle, then exception will come as it is in the middle of Iteration.

Answer (score 2):

As other suggested you cannot change a String reason being, Code snippet:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestString {
public void remove5() {
    Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
    newSet.add("hello");
    newSet.add("my");
    newSet.add("name");
    newSet.add("is");
    newSet.add("nonsense");
    for (Iterator<String> iter = newSet.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        if (iter.next().length() == 5) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newSet);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestString().remove5();
}
}
```

If you iterate over the set and in the loop you remove the object, it will throw you `ConcurrentModificationException`as `HastSet` iterator is a fail fast Iterator.

Comment: It would be worth explaining why this works where the other answers resulted in a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

Comment: Updated my answer to cater to it.

Answer (score 2):

For actually modifying your set, you need to do something like this:

```
Iterator<String> iter = newSet.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
    if (iter.next().length() == 5)
        iter.remove();
```

Since Strings are immutable, you can't modify the ones that were already added to the set, and anyway, even if you could modify them in-place, replacing them by "" would not remove them from the set.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are `immutable`, changes made to the String `word` or any other String will not reflect in the string of `Set`

add

```
if(word.length()==5)
    {
        word.replaceAll(word, "");
        newSet.remove(word);
    }
```

you can refer to this function of HashSet

```
remove(Object o)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: So then how do I modify the strings?

Comment: you can remove element from Set, please see the edited answer @MacosxIam

Comment: This gives me an error - Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: You need to remove the object, I have placed the code in my answer

Comment: it gives you concurrentmodificationexception because while iterating you try to remove it, and Set is a fast fail collection.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Java, that means when you call `word.replaceAll(word,"")`, it returns the String "" (which you aren't assigning to anything). The **word** doesn't change and the Set is still pointing to the old value of **word**. You need to remove **word** from the Set itself.

Comment: I tried this: newSet.remove(word); but it gives me an error - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: You are removing from the Set while you are iterating through it. You could try to create a new Set, *add the Strings that are **not** of legnth 5*, then assign `newSet = (the set you just created to hold the non-length-5 Strings)`

Comment: Or do what @Prince John Wesley suggested, by iterating through an array of the Set instead of the set itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a string of length 5, you need to remove it from the set:

```
newSet.remove(word);
```

As it is, you appear to be trying to change word to an empty string, but strings are immutable.  What your call actually does is return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
Set<String> newSet = new HashSet<String>();
newSet.add("hello");
newSet.add("my");
newSet.add("name");
newSet.add("is");
newSet.add("nonsense");
for(String word: newSet)
{
   if(word.length()==5)
   {
       newSet.remove(i);
   }
   i++;
}
```